# Why does .change() not work on the datalist element? Is there an alternative?

Tags: jquery, html, html-datalist

I've done a bit of googling on the topic but since browser support for the datalist element is still pretty poor, it seems like no one is using it or hasn't really asked this question before.  I have a datalist:

```
<form>

     <input placeholder="Enter a location or choose from the list" list="restaurants" id="hp-restaurants">

     <datalist id="restaurants">
         <option value="Sanford, ME" data-attr="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/locations/weathervane-restaurants/sanford/" />
         <option value="Kitery, ME" data-attr="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/locations/weathervane-restaurants/kittery/" />
         <option value="Belfast, ME" data-attr="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/locations/lobster-in-the-rough/belfast/" />
         <option value="Waterville, ME" data-attr="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/locations/weathervane-restaurants/waterville/" />
         <option value="Brewer, ME" data-attr="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/locations/weathervane-restaurants/brewer/" />
         <option value="South Portland, ME" data-attr="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/locations/weathervane-restaurants/south-portland/" />
         <option value="Bedford, NH" data-attr="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/locations/weathervane-restaurants/bedford-nh/" />
         <option value="Dover, NH" data-attr="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/locations/weathervane-restaurants/dover-nh/" />
         <option value="Chichester, NH" data-attr="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/locations/weathervane-restaurants/chichester-nh/" />
         <option value="Salem, NH" data-attr="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/locations/weathervane-restaurants/salem-nh/" />
         <option value="West Lebanon, NH" data-attr="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/locations/weathervane-restaurants/west-lebanon-nh/" />
         <option value="Nashua, NH" data-attr="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/locations/weathervane-restaurants/nashua-nh/" />
     </datalist>

</form>
```

Each one of the options is supposed to link to the page in the data-attr attribute that I've added in there. If there's an easier way to get those options to link to pages, I'm just ignorant of it. This is the first time I'm attempting to do anything with the datalist element. So feel free to take me to school if I'm just doing this wrong in a fundamental way.

At the moment, I'm trying to trigger an even when the drop down list changes. I thought that jQuery's .change() event would handle that but it's not. Anyway, I'm testing the event to see if it triggers with this:

```
$('#hp-restaurants').click(function() {
    console.log('HELLO WORLD');
});
```

No dice.

Any advice on getting this element to link to those pages when the options list changes?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you using a browser that actually supports datalist elements?

Comment: Binding both click and change events work for me in Chrome... http://jsfiddle.net/filoxo/L7zu9/ NOTE: the change event doesn't fire until focus has been moved from the datalist.

Comment: @Powerlord I'm devving in Chrome. As far as I know, Chrome supports it. At least, the .click() event in jQuery works on that element when I test it. I'm just not looking to use that event.

Comment: Hmm... well, using the link @filoxo posted, onchange works in Firefox 29.0.1, but not until I unfocus the datalist element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're looking to fire an event when a datalist option has been selected, rather than waiting until the `change` event (which is fired when a new option has been selected **and** focus is given to another element) you should bind to the `input` event, like so:

```
 $('#hp-restaurants').on('input', function () {
    console.log('Input has been changed.');
 });
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/filoxo/L7zu9/2/) | See also MDN docs for ['oninput'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput)

Comment: That's the one. I didn't know that I had to bind to the input. That's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure I even knew about the oninput event? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.oninput

Comment: Thanks I had a issue in Chrome as I was using $("#advance-search input").on("select", function(e){}

Comment: Seems like Microsoft Edge does not emit an `input` event for `datalist` selections.